# Respective sorting of two 3D arrays

Tags: matlab, sorting

people. I was not able to find an answer on my question.

Let's say we have two 3D arrays:

```
A=rand(10,10,3);
B=rand(10,10,3);
```

Then we sort A along the 3rd demension:

```
[sorted_A, idx] = sort(A,3);
```

How should I act to set the same ordering in the second array?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need linear indexing, like this:

```
[ii jj ] = ndgrid(1:size(A,1),1:size(A,2));
sorted_B = B(sub2ind(size(A),repmat(ii,[1 1 size(A,3)]),repmat(jj,[1 1 size(A,3)]),idx));
```

Comment: Thanks @Luis Mendo, this example will help me too. I have something like that to do for a job :)

Comment: @AlexandreBizeau I'm glad about that!

Answer (score 1):

With the sort on the first matrix, you obtain the index of each sort.

Just do `C = B(idx)`  (Working for 1D array)

**EDIT**

This is for a 3D matrix but this solution isn't vectorize.

```
C = zeros(10,10,3);

for dim = 1:3
    for it = 1:10
        for jt = 1:10
            C(it,jt,dim) = B(it,jt,idx(it,jt,dim));
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Yes, I figure it out. I was working on 3D sorting, right now.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand you. You're saying that your solution is working for you?

Comment: No problem. If I find something well working(in vectorized form) - I'll post it here.

Comment: When you say, well working, is it because by for..loop doesn't work for you ?

Comment: No,no. I mean when I get something well-working in vectorized form. Your solution works properly - I've checked it.